# Implement String's valueOf function, code review request

Tags: java

Ok, code reviewers, I want you to pick my code apart and give me some feedback on how I could make it better or more simple.

```
public final class StringValueOf {

    private StringValueOf () {}

    // note that int max value is 10 digits
    final static int [] sizeTable = { 9, 99, 999, 9999, 99999, 999999, 9999999,
        99999999, 999999999, Integer.MAX_VALUE };

    private final static char[] DigitOne = {
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
    };


    private final static char[] DigitTens = {
        '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
        '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
        '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
        '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
        '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
        '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
        '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6',
        '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7',
        '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8',
        '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9',
    };


    private static int stringSize(int x) {
        for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
            if (x <= sizeTable[i]) {
                return i + 1;
            }
        }
    }


    private static void getChars (char[] buf, int size, int i) {
        int charPos = size - 1;

        if (i < 0) {
            i = -i;
        }

        while (i >= 10) {
            int r = i % 100;
            i = i / 100;

            buf[charPos--]  = DigitOne[r];
            buf[charPos--]  = DigitTens[r];
        }

        if (i > 0) {
            buf[charPos--] = DigitOne[i];
        }

        if (charPos == 0) {
            buf[charPos] = '-';
        }
    }

    public static String valueOf(int i) {
        if (i == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return "-2147483648";
        }
        int size = (i < 0) ? stringSize(-i ) + 1 : stringSize(i);
        char[] buf = new char[size];

        buf.toString();

        getChars(buf, size, i);

        /**
         * There are 2 ways to convert a char into string.
         * 1. buf.toString()
         * 2. String(buf)
         * 
         * but we should use String(buf) because:
         * 1. Mostly buf.toString would internally call String(buf)
         * 2. Integer class uses new String.
         */
        return new String(buf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(valueOf(101));
        System.out.println(valueOf(-2010));
    }  
}
```

Comment: The `buf.toString()` doesn't do anything. Also, don't you mean to test for `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and return `-2147483648`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would replace (just to reduce size of the source-code

```
private final static char[] DigitOne = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
};


private final static char[] DigitTens = {
    '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0',
    '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1',
    '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2',
    '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3', '3',
    '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4',
    '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5',
    '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6',
    '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7', '7',
    '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8',
    '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9', '9',
};
```

by

```
private final static char[] DigitOne = 
      ("0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789" //
      +"0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789"+"0123456789")
      .toCharArray();
};


private final static char[] DigitTens = {
     ("0000000000"+ "1111111111"+"2222222222"+"3333333333"+"4444444444" //
     +"5555555555"+"6666666666"+"7777777777"+"8888888888"+"9999999999")
      .toCharArray();             
};
```

Or even generate the constants with a static method using loops.

If you want to avoid speed loss by the loop, unroll it completely.
There are only 10 possible cases for the length. With a binary-decision you can determine the length with 4 if-statements and than convert the value without any loop at all. Code would get a bit long, but also very fast.

Comment: Is there a `+` missing in your initialization of DigitOne? Also shouldn't `static final`s be UPPER_SNAKE_CASE?

Comment: @Bobby: Thanks for the missing `+` hint, I fixed it. And I have not changed the names of the variables, because that is pure convention.

Comment: @MrSmith42 String concat is a very expensive operation, check that section of effective java encouraging string builders instead of string concay

Comment: @JavaDeveloper Static string concatenation is now resolved at compile time. But it didn't used to be; so it's no longer expensive at runtime.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: String concat is only performed once while initialization of the constants, if not already at compile time. Therefore this should be no performance issue.

Comment: While I do thank everyone involved - but still not completely convinced, .toCharArray() is run not at compile time, making this approach marginally inefficient

Comment: @JavaDeveloper: That ok, because the `.toCharArray()` method call is done only once while loading the class.

Answer (score 5):

Since it's easy to convert integer digits to their character values ('0' = 0x30..'9' = 0x39), why not:

```
public static String stringValueOf(int value) {
  if (value == 0) return "0";
  if (value == Integer.MIN_VALUE) return "-2147483648";

  final boolean negative = value < 0;
  if (negative) value = -value;

  final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
  while (value != 0) {
    int digit = value % 10;
    buf.append( (char)(0x30 + digit) );
    value = value / 10;
  }
  if (negative) buf.append('-');

  return buf.reverse().toString();
}
```

It's easy to test this for correctness over the int range; but to do so, I'd extract the `StringBuilder` construction from the method into a static class variable and just call `buf.setLength(0)` each time.

Comment: I have some reservations in terms of efficiency. 1. Stringbuilder is less efficient then char array of fized capacity. 2. Your while loop takes twice more iterations. Rest I do admit your code is cleaner and concise

Comment: You can change the implementation of this answer to use `char[]` instead of `StringBuilder` if you prefer it. And the more iterations should not be as bad as you may think

Comment: Minor nitpick, you could directly return `Integer.MIN_VALUE.ToString()` instead of a hardcoded string. Would mostly improve readability. ... Or you could pull those two ifs together and return `Integer.toString(value)`.

Comment: @Bobby The only reason I took the convenience of hard-coding the MIN_VALUE as a special case is because of two's complement format and negation; `-MIN_VALUE == MIN_VALUE` in 2's complement. I thought the whole point of this exercise was to re-implement `Integer.toString()`, so you wouldn't be allowed to call what you're re-implementing (otherwise what's the point?)

Comment: Was the point of this to maximize speed? That wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper `StringBuilder` *is* a char array of fixed size with a nice API over it (unless it needs to reallocate, which it won't in this case because by default it allocates 16 chars and the maximum length of `Int` bounds is 12 digits plus negation).